# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating ExpoFontLoader.loadAsync)

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
   View, 
   TextInput,
} from 'react-native';
import Icons from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

class EmployeeFrom extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
     <View>
       <View>
         <Icons name="user" size={28}
         style={styles.InputIcons}
         />
         <TextInput style={styles.textInput} 
                placeholder="Name"
                placeholderTextColor="black"
                underlineColorAndroid="rgba(0,0,0,0)"
         />
       </View>
      </View>
    );
   }
  }
```

I imported the vector Icons form react-native-vector-icons but still I'm getting the error can any one please help me

Comment: I think the default import is Icon instead of Icons

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I was helped to level the versions of the expo and the version.

It was:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^30.0.1",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.
}
```

**app.json**

```
"expo": {
  "sdkVersion": "29.0.0",
}
```

It became:

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "expo": "^30.0.1",
  "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.
}
```

**app.json**

```
"expo": {
  "sdkVersion": "30.0.0",
}
```

Comment: You can also use icons from expo, instead of third-party modules.
Documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/icons
Examples of icons: https://expo.github.io/vector-icons/